# Submitting apps to Android Market and Amazon Appstore

Tags: android, google-play, amazon-appstore

I have an application signed and all ready to go public. But I want to stage it and make a simultaneous release on both Amazon Appstore and Android Market. I have a few questions which I couldn't find a right answer anywhere.

1. After I pay 25$ to create my account at android market, how long does it take for the account to be active?
2. I know there is no review process. But is it possible to upload my .apk file and not publish it?

Now regarding Amazon appstore -

1. How long does it take for my account to be active after I create it?
2. How long does the application review process take?
3. How long does it take after the application is reviewed for the application to go live?
4. Is it possible for me to upload apk, get it reviewed and wait before I publish it?

Comment: I can't tell you about Amazon but for the traditional market there is definitely the option to upload without publishing (for the first upload and for any updates as well)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android Makret:

1. It depends. For me it was almost immediate, but recently some people are reporting it takes some time (1-2 days)
2. Yes.

Amazon:

1. It's activated right away.
2. It depends. Might be two days, might be a week, maybe longer.
3. It's not exactly clear, but the review process apparently has a few different stages. There is an 'approved' and 'live' state, so it might take some time in between.
4. No.

The real question: why does it matter to you? If you submit an app, it should be in a ready to release state.

Comment: thanks for the info. but i see that we can actually choose a publish date in amazon app store. but thanks for lot of other right answers :)

Comment: Right, completely forgot about those. I've never used them, but those should work for the initial release. For updates, though, I'm not sure if you can control the availability date. Do report back if you find out.

Answer (score 3):

android

1 instant
2 yes, you upload it, then you have to publish it.

No clue on the Amazon one though, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Now is free for 12 months

It took me an hour or so for the submission process